# Remove transparent space from a png image while merging with another png image using PHP GD

Tags: php, image, gd

I am merging two png images in my php code using php-gd. The images are getting merged, however the problem is that there is extra transparent space in the image which I want to remove.

Here is my php code.

```
<?php

$image1Url = "/home/sunpure-refined-sunflower-oil-v-5-ltr-1.png";
$image2Url = "/home/hypercity-every-day-sooji-rawa-v-1-kg-6.png";    

$dest = imagecreatefrompng($image1Url);
$src = imagecreatefrompng($image2Url);

$offset2x = imagesx($src);
$offset3x = imagesx($dest);

$temp = imagecreatetruecolor($offset2x + $offset3x, 140);
$background = imagecolorallocate($temp, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($temp, $background);

imagecopymerge($temp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 180, 100); //have to play with these numbers for it to work for you, etc.
imagecopymerge($temp, $dest, $offset2x-50, 0, 0, 0, 180, 180, 100);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($temp, "/home/myImage.png");

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

[image: Here is my merged image]
[image: Here is my second image where I am trying to overlap some part of the image to first image. However there is extra transparent space which does not look good]

In the rightmost image, I was trying to remove the space between them , but due to transparent space, its not happening.